# Event driven and asynchronous serial port communication simultaneously

Tags: java, asynchronous, serial-port

I'm completely new to serial port communication and need some help grasping it.

I need to communicate with a control board. This board can sometimes send events that I need to react to, and I need to send events to the board and await a response.

We have established a protocol where each event is always 12 bytes and the first 2 bytes determine the event type.

I know that when I send a specific message, I need to await a message with specific signifying bytes. *At the same time* I want it to be possible to react to events that are sent from the board. For instance the board might say that it is overheating, and at the same time I'm asking it to perform some command and reply.

My question is, if I write to the port and block for a second while awaiting the expected response, how I do ensure I don't "steal" the data my listener expects? E.g. do a serial ports work like a stream, where once I've read I've advanced past the point where it can be re-read.

I've done some implementation of this using [jSerialComm](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm), hopefully this can shed some light on my question.

First a listener that is registered using the [addDataListener](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html#addDataListener-com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortDataListener-) method. I want this to trigger when an event is present on the port that starts with "T".

```java
private static LockerSerialPort getLockerSerialPort(final DeviceClient client) {
    return MySerialPort.create(COM_PORT)
            .addListener(EventListener.newBuilder()
                    .addEventHandler(createLocalEventHandler())
                    .build());
}

private static EventHandler createLocalEventHandler() {
    return new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void execute(final byte[] event) {
                System.out.println(new String(event));
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getEventIdentifier() {
                // I want this listener to be executed when events that start with T are sent to the port
                return "T".getBytes();
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "T handler";
            }
        };
}
```

Next, I want to be able to write to the port and immediately get the response because it is needed to know if the command was successful or not.

```
private byte[] waitForResponse(final byte[] bytes) throws LockerException {
    write(bytes);
    return blockingRead();
}

private void write(final byte[] bytes) throws LockerException {
    try (var out = serialPort.getOutputStream()) {
        out.write(bytes);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw Exception.from(e, "Failed to write to serial port %s", getComPort());
    }
}

public byte[] blockingRead() {
    return blockingRead(DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT);
}

private byte[] blockingRead(final int readTimeout) {
    serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, readTimeout, 0);
    try {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[PACKET_SIZE];
        final int bytesRead = serialPort.readBytes(readBuffer, readBuffer.length);
        if (bytesRead != PACKET_SIZE) {
            throw RuntimeException.from(null, "Expected %d bytes in packet, got %d", PACKET_SIZE, bytesRead);
        }
        return readBuffer;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw RuntimeException.from(e, "Failed to read packet within specified time (%d ms)", readTimeout);
    }
}
```

When I call `waitForResponse("command")`, how do I know my blocking read doesn't steal data from my listener?

Are these two patterns incompatible? How would one usually handle a scenario like this?

Comment: *"How would one usually handle a scenario like this?"* -- Have a thread that is always reading the serial port and validating the messages.  Every valid message generates an event.  Events can be solicited or unsolicited.  The response message is a solicited event that the send-command procedure is waiting for.  An overheating report is an unsolicited event.

Comment: Thanks! So basically pub/sub where the unsolicited events don't have subscribers?